# Discоrd Bot Event

Tags: python, arrays, events, discord, bots

is it possible to somehow put before.rules and after.sales into two arrays, then compare the number of elements in them and subtract not their number, but the elements, so that the rest can be output later?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Oz6.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To compare the lengths of two lists, you can:

```
>>> print(len(after.roles)-len(before.roles))
3
```

In this example 3 new roles were gained